# Databinding a D3 slider with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, d3.js

I've managed to create a D3 slider (modified from some previous examples) and at the moment I'm trying to bind it to Knockout. My ultimate use case requires a large number of sliders on screen at the same time and being able to modify values via a calculation engine underneath - knockout should provide a great way of doing this.

My problem is trying to figure out how to data-bind the objects together, I was planning on using some custom bindings, but can't figure out how to actually get my object. A brief code example of my slider:

```
custom.d3.slider = function () {
    var slider = { };
    var value;

    slider.value = function (_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return value;
        _update(_);
        return slider;
    };

    slider.appendTo = function (target) {

         var sliderBar = target.append("g")
            .attr("class", "slider " + cssClass)
            .attr("data-bind", "slide: 0.5")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")")
            .call(d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(xScale)
                .tickSize(0) // ensure that end ticks are not displayed
                .ticks([])) // ensure that no ticks are included in the DOM
            .select(".domain") // this is a custom class added by D3
            .select(function () {
                return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true));
            })
            .attr("class", "inner-bar")
            .select(function () {
                return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true));
            })
        .attr("class", "fill-bar");

    };

    return slider;
}
```

So after this point I want to set my custom binding, I've currently defined the following binding with a debugger statement to try and see what's going on:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slide = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var d = d3.select(element);   
        debugger;
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
         var d = d3.select(element);   
        debugger;
    }
};
```

This gets me what I believe is a D3 object (rather than a DOM object):

[image]

The problem I can't figure out, is how to actually get to my `slider.value()` function from here. Is it even possible to do or am I going about this the wrong way? [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/oqebb0qz/).

I have managed to get one solution [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/md61de9d/2/), but it just feels the wrong way to be going about doing it, which is to manually update the view model and subscribe to events:

```
slider.callback(function(context, value) {
                        vm.myVal(value);
                        console.log(context.value());
                });
var vm = {
    myVal: ko.observable(0.5)  
};

vm.myVal.subscribe(function(v) { 
   slider.value(v); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting all the logic of the slider in the slide bindingHandler. Your init should instantiate a new slider and the update should update the slider's value, for example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slide = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var valueObservable = valueAccessor();
        element.__slider__ = custom.d3.slider()
                    .configure({
                        minimumValue: 0,
                        maximumValue: 1,
                        value: 0.5          
                    })
                    .margin({ top: 20, left: 40})
                    .appendTo(element)
                    .callback(function (context, value) {
                        valueObservable(context.value());
                    });
        // or when you're using jQuery, use the .data function to store the 
        // slider instance: $(element).data('slider', ...);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        element.__slider__.value(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
    }
};
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/v8tvkb4j/

Comment: Nice - I need to figure out how to achieve that (as currently my visualization adds sliders to itself) but you've demo'd the approach perfectly.